# what redirect method is being used

Tags: redirect, fiddler

I was trying to access http://www.shanimusic.net using FF and was redirected to a myspace address.

When  looking at fiddler, it seems like the myspace address was the only thing used and there is no evidence of the actual domain i entered.

Can I tell using fiddler if it is using a 301 or a meta redirect?
if not, are there other ways to tell?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell by simply asking the web server:

```
$ telnet www.shanimusic.net 80
Trying 64.202.189.170...
Connected to shanimusic.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.shanimusic.net

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2011 18:18:57 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Location: http://www.myspace.com/shanimusic
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0

Connection closed by foreign host.
```